# TypeScript ReturnType of async function

Tags: typescript

I have this example:

```
async function main() {
  const foo = async () => {
    return "foo";
  };

  let fooResult: ReturnType<typeof foo>;

  fooResult = await foo();
}

main();
```

But TS fails to compile with `let fooResult: Promise<string> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Promise<string>'`

What am I missing in typing the return type of an async function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [Awaited](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#awaitedtype) to define the type based on an asynchronous function which returns `Promise<string>`:

```
let fooResult: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof foo>>; //string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwLbFRACgEoYBvAKBhikxGXnXRgF4ZRJZiWA+MyqmACcApsgSCsAIjiNJAbn4BfBfwA2ohugBKwkAlXIAXDACCAdzzJhAEwA8OsRIAqYAA7DbyN8PRxN3bgUqAHpgqgA9AH5+GW1dfXpWYAtUeljiBUVyclx8DKA)

The `await foo();` statement unwraps the promise and returns a `string` type so `fooResult` has to be a `string` type as well